Failed to open file composer.json. Please verify the archive error in commercedeveloper
My composer file is below
    "name": "mymodule/module-shipping",
    "description": "Description of module",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4",
        "magento/framework": "~100.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Mymodule\\Shipping\\": ""
        }
    }
}

My zip file name is mymodule_shipping1.0.0.zip
Please help me.
Thanks in Advance

